# No unused expressions in mocha chai unit test using standardJS

Tags: javascript

I am using standardJS for testing my code. Also I am using mocha chai. With that I'm getting the error `expect an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.` for this line:

```
expect(err).to.be.null
```

But this line is correct, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this line is triggering the issue? What is `err` ?

Comment: Yes. I tried an blank JS file. Better example: `expect(null).to.be.null`

Comment: Are you sure it's a JS error and not a linting error?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I'm also getting this error running `standard` at the terminal

Comment: If you are using the jshint you can add this to your .jshintrc `"expr": true`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions:

**1. Use [`dirty-chai`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dirty-chai)**

Using `dirty-chai` you can change this:

```
expect(err).to.be.null
```

to this:

```
expect(err).to.be.null()
```

Use it like this:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var dirtyChai = require('dirty-chai');
var expect = chai.expect

chai.use(dirtyChai);

expect(err).to.be.null()
```

---

**2. Disable the rule** by adding a comment to the top of each test file

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-expressions */
```

---

**Note:** *Please read [this comment](https://github.com/standard/standard/issues/690#issuecomment-278533482) for more information.*

Comment: Disable the rule. Don't add another dependency to your system.

Answer (score 1):

StandardJS/ESLint expects either the expression to be assigned to a variable or a function to be called instead. So to avoid this error you can replace the `null` property with the `equal` method:

```
expect(err).to.be.equal(null)
```